# What is Kotlin's functional equivalent for finally?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, finally

This example is from the documentation of HttpUrlConnection:

```java
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
}
finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

The documentation says:

> Once the response body has been read, the HttpURLConnection should be closed by calling disconnect().

I tried use the Java class to load an image in a functional style:

```kotlin
fun fetch (url: String): ImageBitmap =
    URL(url)
        .openConnection()
        .also { it.setRequestProperty (authorization.header, authorization.basicauth()) }
        .getInputStream()
        .buffered()
        .use { BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it) }
        .asImageBitmap()
```

Now I am wondering how to add the `disconnect` call?

I want to achieve this:

```kotlin
fun fetch (url: String): ImageBitmap {
    var connection: HttpURLConnection? = null
    return try {
        URL(url)
            .openConnection()
            .also { it.setRequestProperty(authorization.header, authorization.basicauth()) }
            .also { connection = it as HttpURLConnection }
            .getInputStream()
            .buffered()
            .use { BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it) }
            .asImageBitmap()
    } finally {
        connection?.disconnect()
    }
}
```

But in a less ugly manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a stdlib solution for your case, but kotlin has the [use()](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/io/Closeable.kt#L21) extension method defined on (Auto)Closeable to make this pattern more functional for those interfaces.

You could add a `use` extension method to HttpUrlConnection yourself that calls its disconnect() method, using the same approach as the source of [use](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/f3385fbdcb8b9dc29661a8a4973c855cdcf73767/libraries/stdlib/jvm/src/kotlin/io/Closeable.kt#L21).

Of course you would still need to write the try finally once, but it is now hidden when using HttpUrlConnection.

On first sight you'd end up with something like this, you might still need some null handling somewhere.

```
public fun <T : HttpURLConnection, R> T.use(block: (T) -> R): R {
    try {
        return block(this)
    } finally {
        disconnect()
    }
}

(URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection).use {
   // do things with connection `it`
}
// connection is now disconnected()
```

Comment: But `HttpURLConnection` is not `Closeable`. And the code does not work: https://pl.kotl.in/WxujwxDr3

Comment: That's my point, you need to create the extension function yourself, and call disconnect() instead of close(), hence why I linked the source code of `use`.

Comment: @somethingsomething you should probably clarify that in the code snippet, by adding the implementation of the custom `use` extension. And I agree that's the best way to go IMO if OP doesn't want a `finally` there

Comment: I added a minimal code example for the extension method, but I don't have anything handy to test it so there might be a typo.

Answer (score 2):

Your existing way of doing this is clear enough as it is. Kotlin is not a purely functional language, so trying to use higher-order functions *all the time* can sometimes make your code *harder* to read (See also [Principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)), not to mention that you are using a *Java* API, which isn't designed for something like this at all.

One way I've thought of though, is:

```
fun fetch (url: String) =
    (URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection).apply {
        runCatching {
            setRequestProperty(authorization.header, authorization.basicauth())
            inputStream
                .buffered()
                .use { BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it) }
                .asImageBitmap()
        }.also { disconnect() }.getOrThrow()
    }
```

I do the entire operation that could through inside a `runCatching` to catch any exceptions, disconnect from the connection, then throw the exception back out again.

In terms of the order of execution, this should be the same as `try...finally` like this:

```
fun fetch (url: String): ImageBitmap {
    val connection = URL(url).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    return try {
        connection
            .also { it.setRequestProperty(authorization.header, authorization.basicauth()) }
            .getInputStream()
            .buffered()
            .use { BitmapFactory.decodeStream(it) }
            .asImageBitmap()
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect()
    }
}
```

Comment: If there really is a need to abstract away the `finally`, I would personally prefer a custom `use` extension (using `finally` internally) over the `runCatching` hack. But given that `finally` is part of the `try` expression, it is technically already compatible with functional approaches, and as you said it's really clear this way already.